# the assignment target must be an assignable variable,property or indexer

Tags: c#

Iwant make avg int which cant divide to 10 but the error is: The assignment target must be an assignable variable,property or indexer.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace Cat_claw
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count;
            count = 3;
            int x;
            int sum = 0;
            int avg = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <=2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <=3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("pleasd enter your grade"+count);
                    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    sum += x;
                    avg / 10 = sum;
                      count--; 
                } 
                 Console.WriteLine("your average is"+sum);
             
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi everyone. Iwant to  make avg int which cant divide to 10 but the error is: The assignment target must be an assignable variable,property or indexer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the requirement "Iwant to make avg int which cant divide to 10". Could you clarify? Perhaps provide some sample input and the output you'd like to get for it?

Comment: Gratitude for your respond.

Comment: i want divide sum to 10 to recieve the average but this error occurs.

Comment: Why divide by 10 if you're inputting six numbers?

Comment: sorry ma bad. unfortunately idont undrestand how to make a variable which can divide sum to 10. could you help me?

Comment: I think I understand your question. You have a set of grades that you want to come to a number from 0-10 just like the numerical grade scale used in some schools. I will work on an answer for that but this seems to be a homework question ...if it is, you should ask your teacher for help.

Comment: `avg / 10 = sum;` what should that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an array of scores and you want to combine them to an average between 0 and 10.

Well, that's a simple math problem:

```
namespace Cat_claw
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many scores will you like to enter?");
                int numbOfScores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int totalScore = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < numbOfScores; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter score #" + i);
                    totalScore += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The average is " + (totalScore/numbOfScores));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```